# Reading notes at the Kotel/Western Wall

Tags: tefilla, kotel-western-wall, chesed-kindness

Someone told me that (1) they took a note out of the Kotel wall, read it, and then (2) prayed for the person who placed the note and their prayer.
Is (1) okay, and is it okay (or beautiful) if they do (2)? Do others discuss this?

Comment: Possibly related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23296/759

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37428

Comment: Both these answers assume that there isn't a _norm_ to read them, which is part of what I was asking.

Comment: @MichoelR no, there isn't a norm to read the letters. People assume, when they put a note in the Kotel, that it will never be read.